# List packages apt-get upgrade will omit

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian

Running Debian (Rasbian), I am managing packages via the `apt-*` tools. My computer has entered a state where `apt-get upgrade` lists:

```
# apt-get upgrade                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  example-pkg1 example-pkg2
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get # kB of archives.
```

For each `update`, the number of packages to update will vary, of course, but I will always see the `1 not upgraded` message. `apt-mark showhold` lists nothing, and `apt-get autoremove` has nothing to remove. How do I determine which package will not upgrade?

Comment: This differs from [the question about the packages that apt-get will keep back](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255390/13308).

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when you go to upgrade your machine with apt-get you will see that a package is being "kept back".

To fix this you must run :

`apt-get dist-upgrade`

This will upgrade the packages that have newer versions available, and install any new dependencies which are required to do that.

You can use

`apt-get -u upgrade --assume-no`

to show the upgradable packages.

Comment: As you [see in my output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414888/13308), and differing from [the similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255390/13308), `apt-get` gives no mention of packages is has "kept back".

Comment: I did try `apt-get dist-upgrade` and it didn't update the package in question or indicate which package it would not upgrade.